# navigator.deviceMemory is Undefined on remote webserver, but works when used from a .html file

Tags: javascript

I have a question- when i do `console.log(navigator.deviceMemory + "GB RAM");` locally, it works no problem

When I run that JS on my web application, it doesnt work.

My output is:

> Undefined

Heres my code on the dev site:

```
function checkRequirements()
{
    var cpu = window.navigator.hardwareConcurrency;

    var ram = window.navigator.deviceMemory;

    if (cpu > 2 && ram > 2)
    {
        console.log("yes");
    }
    else
    {
        console.log(ram);
    }
}
```

Also, i'm new at JS, this is literally the first thing i've done with it.

Cant find much on Google about this exact problem

Thanks.

EDIT:
So i used this exact code on another website i manage, and it worked. Its a live environment. I don't flipping know why this wont work on my dev environment. [This Mozilla Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/deviceMemory#Browser_compatibility) shows that it should work in Chrome. I'm lost and confused. I'm gonna leave this for now. Thanks for every ones help.

Comment: Those APIs are not widely supported.

Comment: @Pointy But it works from an html file on my desktop, but the same code hosted on a remote server doesnt work. I said it in my comment to the answer below, but i dont understand how the two differ...

Comment: You have not posted enough code for anybody to really help. How is your JavaScript code imported into your HTML? Are you 100% sure that that's working?

Comment: @Pointy Yeah, i'm 100% sure its working properly. navigator.hardwareConcurrency works, but device navigator.deviceMemory doesn't. I'm just puzzled how this works from an html file on my desktop and not when i go to a website to do it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it looks like its a security feature- `navigator.deviceMemory` REQUIRES HTTPS to work, which is why it's not working for me. You can see this for yourself on the GitHub for this right [here](https://github.com/w3c/device-memory).

Thanks for your help everyone, looks like I wont be able to test this in my dev environment.

Answer (score 0):

`navigator.deviceMemory` is supported only by Chrome, Opera, and the Android mobile browser. It is undefined everywhere else. So unless the server code is running in Chrome (unlikely), you can't use it there.

This website is a useful tool for seeing what browsers support different bits of code: https://caniuse.com/#search=deviceMemory

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by server code is running in chrome? I'm loading the page in chrome in both places. I dont understand how it would work in Chrome locally, but when I load the webpage it becomes undefined? I'm pretty inexperienced, so forgive me if i sound like an idiot. Also, love how I can tell if the devices battery is charging and not how much RAM it has...

Comment: He means that on your computer you run your website in a browser like Chrome for example. Chrome has the `navigator.deviceMemory` property. Your server is not a browser and therefor does not have that property. So accessing that property in the server would return `undefined` because it simply does not have it there. It makes sense if you think about it. In the browser it tells you the memory of the device you are using (laptop, tablet, etc). The server is not using any of those devices. You could **send** the `deviceMemory` value **to** the server.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Okay that kinda makes sense. I thought since getting the `navigator.hardwareConcurrency` worked both from a URL and an HTML Document meant there was something up with my code. Thank you.

Comment: I'm starting to think there's a misunderstanding here. Where are you hosting your website? Is this code on the server or in the HTML file being sent to the client?

Comment: The code was hosted on a development server- with NO https. According to their github documentation for navigator.devicememory, it does need HTTPS to work. I find it strange, because the code works when launched directly from an html document. Anyways, thanks for your help.